# What is the reason for this error? (.Net 5, C#)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-5, asp.net5

I am coding a dynamic website, everything works but I noticed an error in the terminal.

Error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
     at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
     at AspNetCore.Views_Content_CategoryContent.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Projeler\Wutemp\Views\Content\CategoryContent.cshtml:line 2
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)       
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Controller (Edit: I accidentally deleted the ViewBag part):

```
    [Route("Content/{url}/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var content = repoContents.TGet(id);

        //If content has a category, go to CategoryContent
        if(content.ContentCategory != null && content.ContentCategory != 0){
            return RedirectToAction("CategoryContent", new 
            { 
                category = repoContentCategories.TGet((int)content.ContentCategory).Title, 
                url = content.URL, 
                id = content.ID 
            });
        }
        else{
            ViewBag.Content = content;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Comment: **Read the stack trace**: The issue is your  .cshtml file expects a non-null `@model` object, but your controller action just calls `View()` without passing a `model:` argument which then defaults to `null`, which the view doesn’t like.

Comment: (You can avoid problems like these by not using the `View(Object)` methid and instead by having build-time-generated extension methods for every view file in your project, but AFAIK ASP.NET Core does not do this out-of-the-box - just something to consider)

Comment: I shared the code incompletely, now I edited it, the error continues

Comment: The problem **is not** `ViewBag.Content = content;`, the problem is you should be using `return this.View( model: content );` instead of `return View();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I used model instead of ViewBag mentioned in comments it didn't work I kept getting the same error

I think the problem is due to the similarity of the route parts of the 2 Views.

Index:

```
[Route("Content/{url}/{id}")]
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var content = repoContents.TGet(id);

    //If content has a category, go to CategoryContent
    if(content.ContentCategory != null && content.ContentCategory != 0){
        return RedirectToAction("CategoryContent", new 
        { 
            category = repoContentCategories.TGet((int)content.ContentCategory).Title, 
            url = content.URL,
            id = content.ID
        });
    }
    else{
        ViewBag.Content = content;
        return View();
    }
}
```

CategoryContent:

```
[Route("Content/{category}/{url}/{id}")]
public IActionResult CategoryContent(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Content = repoContents.TGet(id);
    return View();
}
```

I solved the problem by changing the Route part of the ContentCategory page

```
[Route("Content/{category}/{url}/{id}")]

           |
           V
          
[Route("Category-Content/{category}/{url}/{id}")]
```